# How can i enable short_open_tag by web.config

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-config

I am having issue with php shorthand tags.

I am using codeigniter and i am calling all the **CSS** and **JS** files with shorthand tags like `<?= base_url('home')?>` but on the page links it opens `<?=%20base_url(%27home%27)?>`

I have checked `phpinfo();` it's show's `short_open_tags = off` How can i ON this feature by `web.config` file because it's windows server.

Comment: You need to edit `php.ini` not `web.config`, regardless of server operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

and set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

---

***In Localhost***

1. **XAMPP**

[image]

2. **WAMP**

[image]

Comment: I am facing error on live server. it's running perfect on localhost Thank You :)

Comment: ask your server provider to active it or access as a **root** `in /usr/local/lib/` then **nano php.ini** and edit the line